# Trying to convert a json object to DataTable

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to convert a json object to `DataTable` using this method:

```
string jsonString="{"data":[{"uid":502458330,"name":"Mustapha Malass","pic_square":"https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/t5/276351_502458330_1748214131_q.jpg","online_presence":"idle"},"

DataTable obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(jsonString.ToString());
```

but I get an error:

> Additional text found in JSON string after finishing deserializing object.

**PS:** I didn't post all my json string because it's too big as you can see the `,` in the end wish point that the json is not complete.

Comment: I suggest you validate it to find if there is any invalid string by some tools. here is a online one http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: it parse it and no error occurred :/

Comment: Please correct you code " to \". So other people can understand better and help you.

Comment: The version of Json.net I used is 6.0.1 . What is the version you use?Could you please post your json string ?If it is two big, please try to remove some elements in the array. then post here .

Comment: If you have the trouble with editing big json. please try this tool http://jsonviewer.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code .

```
String json="....some json string...";

DataTable tester = (DataTable) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, (typeof(DataTable)));
```

It works for me.

And try to search in the google first time when you have problem like this. Trust me ,you are not the only one who got the same problem.

Comment: i tried this code earlier it give me the same error

Comment: I was getting the error until i removed the Data portion of the JSON and was left with just a simple object array. `string jsonString="{[{"uid":502458330,`

Comment: Google Search doesn't give you the full picture if you only search for "...json to datatable". In my case I had a json array. Totally different beast! b.Pell's answer worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the most efficient but you could just loop over your JSON if it's not nested and create the DataTable. I wrote this in VB.Net and used a converter to switch it to C# (I came across this question when I was trying to do the same thing and the common snippits weren't working for me). Old question but I thought I'd share for posterity:

```
public static DataTable JsonToDataTable(string json, string tableName)
{
    bool columnsCreated = false;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable(tableName);

    Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject root = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json);
    Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray items = (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray)root[tableName];

    Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject item = default(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject);
    Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken jtoken = default(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken);

    for (int i = 0; i <= items.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        // Create the columns once
        if (columnsCreated == false)
        {
            item = (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)items[i];
            jtoken = item.First;

            while (jtoken != null)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty)jtoken).Name.ToString()));
                jtoken = jtoken.Next;
            }

            columnsCreated = true;
        }

        // Add each of the columns into a new row then put that new row into the DataTable
        item = (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)items[i];
        jtoken = item.First;

        // Create the new row, put the values into the columns then add the row to the DataTable
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

        while (jtoken != null)
        {
            dr[((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty)jtoken).Name.ToString()] = ((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty)jtoken).Value.ToString();
            jtoken = jtoken.Next;
        }

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    return dt;

}
```

http://www.blakepell.com/convert-json-to-a-datatable-with-c-or-vb-net